# Is it possible to remove WYSIWYG for a certain Custom Post Type?

Tags: custom-post-types, wysiwyg

I dont want to use the WYSIWYG at the top of my Custom Post Type. I want to use a custom field textarea that i can place at bottom of my list of custom fields instead.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
add_action('init', 'init_remove_support',100);
function init_remove_support(){
    $post_type = 'your post type';
    remove_post_type_support( $post_type, 'editor');
}
```

place it to your themes functions.php

Comment: Note: I would recommend calling `remove_post_type_support()` inside the same callback that you call `register_post_type()`, to ensure proper order of execution.

Comment: I dont see register_post_type() in functions.php. I am using Custom Types UI in combo with AdvancedCustomFields.

Comment: That you're using the Custom Post Types UI Plugin is a rather important detail to your question. :) The Plugin exposes the `supports` parameter in its UI. [Refer to these screenshots](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/screenshots/).

Comment: This removes both editors (code & visual), not only the visual one - question was about removing WYSIWYG)

Answer (score 22):

You can actually disable the WYSIWYG editor, leaving only the html source editor. Choose a function below:

```
// disable wyswyg for custom post type, using the global $post
add_filter('user_can_richedit', function( $default ){
  global $post;
  if( $post->post_type === 'product')  return false;
  return $default;
});

// disable wyswyg for custom post type, using get_post_type() function
add_filter('user_can_richedit', function( $default ){
  if( get_post_type() === 'product')  return false;
  return $default;
});
```

Comment: is there a way to only remove the WYSIWYG from the excerpt?  My theme has it turned on, and I'm dubious about some of their code, I'm not sure I can remove it.  I asked this as a new question here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/300877/disable-wysiwyg-rich-text-editor-only-on-post-excerpt

Comment: Hi, honestly, I don't know, my WP knowledge is a bit rusty, sorry. The only thing I can suggest is to dig into the WP source code, find something relevant, then duckduckgo/google it for documentation/examples.

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively, you can handle post-editor support directly in your [**`register_post_type()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) call, via the `'supports'` parameter in the `$args` array.

The default value is: `'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor' )`.

You can change it to whatever you need; for example: `'supports' => array( 'title' )`.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer because this is the more rational way to do this !

Answer (score 6):

Re: this comment:

> I am using Custom Types UI in combo with AdvancedCustomFields.

The [**Custom Post Types UI Plugin**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) exposes all of the `register_post_type()` `$args` array parameters in its UI.

In this case, you simply need to find the **Supports** section, and disable/uncheck **Editor**:

[image: Custom Post Types UI Plugin - Register Post Type options]

Comment: Even though another answer was set as the selected answer, this is the correct answer.  There's no need to run a filter to remove something that you can just exclude when declaring the CPT to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to do a more complete answer :

**If you want to remove all the content editor**

The @Oleg Butuzov answer is good :

```
add_action('init', 'init_remove_support',100);
function init_remove_support(){
    $post_type = 'your post type';
    remove_post_type_support( $post_type, 'editor');
}
```

**If you want only disable tinymce but let html toolbars**

The @biziclop answer is good :

```
add_filter('user_can_richedit', function( $default ){
  global $post;
  if( $post->post_type === 'product')  return false;
  return $default;
});
```

In this case `wp-content-editor-tools` is already visible because expand-editor.js insert toolbars.

**If you want to replace the tinymce editor by a simple textarea**

I found the answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/199918/remove-tinymce-from-admin-and-replace-with-textarea).

```
function wpse_199918_wp_editor_settings( $settings, $editor_id ) {
    if ( $editor_id === 'content' && get_current_screen()->post_type === 'custom_post_type' ) {
        $settings['tinymce']   = false;
        $settings['quicktags'] = false;
        $settings['media_buttons'] = false;
    }

    return $settings;
}

add_filter( 'wp_editor_settings', 'wpse_199918_wp_editor_settings', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Another, more consistent way to disable the WYSIWYG editor, leaving only the html source editor - is to disallow tinymce using "wp_editor_settings" filter for your custom post type.

```
function my_post_type_editor_settings( $settings ) {

    global $post_type;

    if ( $post_type == 'my_post_type' ) {

        $settings[ 'tinymce' ] = false;
    }

    return $settings;
}

add_filter( 'wp_editor_settings', 'my_post_type_editor_settings' );
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?