# Remove tinyMCE from admin and replace with textarea

Tags: custom-post-types, tinymce, security, content, sanitization

I have created a plugin wherein I have a custom post type. I am using `post_content` for some simple text. I do not need to offer any fancy editing or insertion of data for this field, so I looked for a way to remove the buttons from the tinyMCE editor.

I never found a very good solution so I removed the `editor` from the custom post type supports in the register function.

```
'supports' => array('title','revisions','thumbnail'),
```

Then to create an area for the content to go I simply echo a `textarea` in the back end form with the `name` and `id` attribute as `"content"`.

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row">
        <label for="content">Review body</label>
    </th>
    <td>
        <textarea style="height: 300px; width: 100%" autocomplete="off" cols="40" name="content" id="content">' . $post->post_content . '</textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This works exactly as I want, and is pretty simple.

The question is, am I losing sanitation or skipping security measures by doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel - put your `editor` support back and tweak the settings:

```
function wpse_199918_wp_editor_settings( $settings, $editor_id ) {
    if ( $editor_id === 'content' && get_current_screen()->post_type === 'custom_post_type' ) {
        $settings['tinymce']   = false;
        $settings['quicktags'] = false;
        $settings['media_buttons'] = false;
    }

    return $settings;
}

add_filter( 'wp_editor_settings', 'wpse_199918_wp_editor_settings', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you! I edited to show the additional media_buttons setting to your answer as I did not want those either.