# Remove TEXT EDITOR form page

Tags: html-editor

I'm looking for a way to remove text editor from page because i'm using Beaver Builder plugin (for building my pages).

like you see in the picture bellow, i have 2 tabs. I want to remove text editor tab (in the red color).

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has an answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72865/is-it-possible-to-remove-wysiwyg-for-a-certain-custom-post-type) . I think this will work for you. Let me know after trying

```
add_action('init', 'init_remove_support',100);
function init_remove_support(){
    $post_type = 'page';
    remove_post_type_support( $post_type, 'editor');
}
```